# Multithreaded client server execution don't end sometimes

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server, threadpool, worker-thread

This is my server code. Performing boss worker. i specify the number of worker of threads. The problem is that sometimes it doesn't reply my client and mostly stuck at receive. Sometimes it execute but only if the client threads are minimum. Client threads sometimes failed to connect.
Can anyone please point out the mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: TLDR; Do you `pthread_join()` your threads after starting them?

Comment: Don't use `puts()`/`printf()` to debug programs, especially multithreaded ones, as `stdout` is usually buffered.  They're also likely to have locks inside the implementation.  You'd do better using OS-specific low-level writes directly to standard error, for example `write( 2, debugString, strlen( debugString );` on POSIX-style systems.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yes i have used . u can see in the last

Comment: Also, that code is too complex.  One bad thing - your main thread always assumes that there's a free thread that it can find.  There doesn't need to be.  You'd do a lot better just using a simple producer-consumer pattern instead of what looks like a producer-consumer-where-the-producer-tries-to-tell-the-consumer-what-to-do pattern. Just do something simple like write the accepted `int` socket value to a pipe and have the threads just read `int`-sized socket values from the pipe, and pass the incoming connections.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out a simple typo in the structure of your code. The reason for that suspicion is that there are two "hidden" curly braces on a line. Run your code through an autoindenter/autoformatter. Firstly, it makes it readable for e.g. people her. I for example am not going to examine it in detail in its current state. Secondly, it makes sure the indentation actually follows the structure, which helps spotting/avoiding the suspected mistake. BTW: There's an awful number of casts in the code, none of which should be strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Checkpoints:**

1. How to make sure that "freeThread+1" be ready for the process. Without checking, in your code, you just try to lock the corresponding mutex.

   ```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex[freeThread+1]);
   ```
2. Why you're sending a signal continuously? You don't need to. Only one time would be enough. Moreover, why you're referring to `isThreadFree` flag? This is not safe-threaded. In case of race condition, it would be wrongly referenced. I think you implement this using `while` because you already experienced this issue.

   ```
   while(isThreadFree[freeThread+1]==true) {
     pthread_cond_signal(&queue_has_client[freeThread+1]);
   }
   ```

**Suggestion:**
I don't think you need to use multiple mutex and cond_signal. Instead, you can use only one single mutex for the queue `clientQueue`and cond.

in `main()` function:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
p = enqueue(clientQueue, client_sock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&queue_has_client);
```

in `worker()` function:

```
while (is_empty_queue(clientQueue)) {
  pthread_cond_wait(&queue_has_client,&queue_mutex);
}
dequeue(clientQueue, &helper);
if (!is_empty_queue(clientQueue))
  wake_up_other_thread = true;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
if (wake_up_other_thread) // to wake up other threads to serve the enqueued clients
  pthread_cond_signal(&queue_has_client);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other posters, your code is way too complex for simply passing accepted sockets to worker threads.

All you need is a queue to pass sockets from the main thread to any available child thread. Instead of implementing a thread-safe queue, you've tried to manage what each thread is doing.

Here's a real simple way, using a pipe as the queue:

```
static int socketPipe[ 2 ];

void *child_thread( void *arg );
{
    while ( 1 ) {
        int mySocket;
        size_t bytesRead = read( socketPipe[ 0 ], &mySocket, sizeof( mySocket ) );
        if ( bytesRead != sizeof( mySocket ) ) {
            // error
        }
        // now handle socket connection in mySocket
    }
    return( NULL );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    // create socket pipe
    int rc = pipe( socketPipe );

    // create threads and listener socket

    // handle incoming connections and pass to child threads
    while ( 1 ) {
        int newConn = accept( mainSocket, &peer, &lenPeer )
        if ( incomingConnection != -1 ) {
            ssize_t written =
                write( socketPipe[ 1 ], &newConn , sizeof( newConn ) );
            // handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

That's pretty much all you need to do to send sockets to child threads.